# Buying reserved instance for t2.xlarge ubuntu

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an Ubuntu running t2.xlarge on an on-demand instance. Now I want to buy 1-year reserved instance for it. I've never done this before and not really a server guy. So I click on the `Purchase Reserved Instance` button in my console and in the drop downs, I selected the values below and click `Search`.

[image]

So is the offerings listed there actually compatible with my ec2.xlarge with ubuntu? What I'm not really sure is the `Platform` there. The reason being is when choosing AMI when creating instance, it seems Ubuntu and Linux are being mentioned differently. I'm worried if I purchased the wrong reserved instance, AWS will charge me for it for whole year. Secondly what is the `Normalized units per hour` there?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Ubuntu is a distribution of Linux.

Comment: @ceejayoz yes I'm aware of that, it's just when selecting AMIs when creating instances, it seems Ubuntu is spoken in different breath to the other linux distros mentioned there. I mean there's `Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8`, `SUSE Linux`, `Amazon Linux`, and then `Ubuntu Server`... this just got me extra worried, especially when needing to commit a 1 year billing

Comment: OK just found this page https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ri-market-concepts-buying.html#ri-choosing-platform and it mentions there `For all other Linux distributions (including Ubuntu), choose an offering for the Linux/UNIX platform.`. But I'm still unsure if the values I selected above reflects my current t2.xlarge

Comment: It plainly says **t2.xlarge** is the instance type! It is right on the screen!

Comment: @MichaelHampton haha yes I know about that, but there's still `Offering class`... anyway maybe I'm just paranoid about nothing lol. OK I will proceed with the order then

Comment: @imin Certain distributions like RHEL have specific licensing that adds extra cost.

Comment: "Offering class" relates to the reserved instance purchase itself, I believe.